# Elegant way to terminate the VirtualBox VBoxSVC.exe process

Tags: windows, virtualbox, services

How do we terminate all the `vbox*.exe` (e.g.: `VBoxSVC.exe`, `VBoxNetDHCP.exe`, `VBoxNetNAT.exe`) processes ***without*** using the OS process signaling tools (e.g.: `taskkill`)?

Comment: Selecting `File` > `Exit` within `VirtualBox.exe` would be a proper way to end these processes.

Comment: They don't exit after I closed the VirtualBox Manager (`VirtualBox.exe`). Probably they are stalled(?). I hope `VBoxManage.exe` has some ways to send termination signals to these processes manually.

Comment: `VirtualBox.exe` is just an interface for managing VirtualBox VMs, it doesn't needs to be running for the VMs to be up.

Answer (score 5):

According to [the user manual ("Chapter 8. VBoxManage")](http://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch08.html), "8.33. VBoxManage metrics":

> ... The data is available as long as the background VBoxSVC process is alive. That process terminates shortly after all VMs and frontends have been closed. ...

Then from "8.35. VBoxManage dhcpserver":

> ... After this, VirtualBox will automatically start the DHCP server for given internal or host-only network as soon as the first virtual machine which uses that network is started. ...

So, `VBoxSVC.exe` should stop automatically. OTOH, I'm guessing but I don't think you'd have any problem stopping `VBoxNetDHCP.exe` and `VBoxNetNAT.exe` with OS signalling, if they don't already stop automatically too. But I don't see why you'd need to stop them.

FWIW, I just had the `VBoxNetAdp.sys` driver crash for lack of memory, killing the network between my VMs, and rerunning `VBoxNetNAT.exe` manually, then `VBoxManage.exe natnetwork start --netname NatNetwork` got the network back without issues. That seems to indicate one would have no problem by stopping it with OS signals.

Comment: Yep, it seems it can take some time (up to several minutes), but it finally terminates itself.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue in Win7 x64, with Docker Toolbox - `VBoxSVC.exe` didn't finish even after shutting down all VMs.

[This advice](https://www.virtualbox.org/ticket/15879#comment:14) from VB issue tracker has helped (thanks to the poster). Open your VirtualBox folder with `cmd.exe` and run `VBoxManage.exe list vms`. `VBoxSVC.exe` disappears shortly from the process tree and doesn't appear hanging afterwards.

Answer (score -1):

Or the easy way is to just press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Del</kbd> and click on the task Manager. The find Oracle box and right click. Then click End Task.

Comment: I wouldn't say this is elegant. And you forgot the Ctrl+Shift+Esc shortcut.

Comment: The asker specifically stated "without using the OS process signaling tools".